# Firebase web - transaction on query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can I run a transaction on a query referring to multiple locations ?

In the doc I see that for example `startAt` returns a `firebase.database.Query` which has a `ref` property of type `firebase.database.Reference` which has the `transaction` method.

So can I do:

```
ref.startAt(ver).ref.transaction(transactionUpdate).then(... ?
```

Would the transaction then operate on multiple locations and update them correctly ?

What I'm trying to do is to get all locations since a particular version (key) and then mark them as 'read' so that a writing client will not update them. For that I need a transaction rather than a simple update.

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "no" to all questions.

1. The `ref` property of a Query gives you the reference of the node on which you set up the query. Consider how you built the query in the first place. In other words, `ref.startAt(x).ref` is equivalent to `ref`.
2. Manipulating a reference (navigating to children, adding query options, etc.) is completely independent of any query results. It's just local, trivial path manipulation, very similar to formatting a URL.
3. Transactions can only operate on a single node, by definition, using that node's value snapshots for incremental updates. They cannot *"operate on multiple locations and update them correctly"*. These are not SQL transactions, the only thing common is the name – which might be, unfortunately, confusing.
4. The starting node doesn't have to be a leaf node. But if you start a transaction on a "parent" node, the client will have to download **every child** to create a whole snapshot, potentially multiple times if any of them is modified by another client.
   This is most certainly a very slow, fragile and *expensive* operation, both for the user and you, the owner of the database. In general, it's not recommended to run transactions if the node might grow unbounded.

---

I suggest revising the presented strategy. Updating "all children" just to store a "read" marker simply does not scale.

You could for example store the last read ID of the client in a single node, and write security rules to enforce that no data with an ID less than this may be modified.

Comment: Thanks ! I understand better now.

The problem with your suggested strategy, is that in the time that storing a 'last read ID' completes, a sending client may change the value.